# Cron and Curl Delete or close Session User

Tags: php, session, curl, automation, cron

hello I have implemented a cron system for ubuntu; which for reasons that I need to run every 30 seconds I had to make some adjustments in conjunction with PHP to achieve the necessary scope.

the problem is that before the implementation everything worked fine; After the implementation I noticed that the user's php sessions are randomly deleted after 1 hour. when it should last up to 8 hours ...

CRON file executed:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/control/cronos/
php cron.php
```

CRON PHP Handler:

```
<?php
$j = 0;
while ($j <= 1) {
    $url    = 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php';
    $fields = array(
        'idprocess' => 'p-cronjobs',
        'idform'    => 'p-cronjobs',
    );
    $postvars         = http_build_query($fields);
    $COOKIE_FILE_PATH = "/tmp/cookiescron.txt";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $j++;
    sleep(25);
}
?>
```

Sistem Handler for PHP Manager Cron Execution:

```
switch ($idform) {
    case "p-cronjobs":
            $stmtpre      = "SELECT TListIdCJ FROM ListCronJobs WHERE TListCJST=1 AND TListCJSTR=0;";
            $data         = $this->DBMANAGER->BDquery($stmtpre, DB_N_LIST);
            $result_exist = $data->num_rows;

            if ($result_exist != 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

                    $fields = array(
                        'idprocess' => $row['TListIdCJ'],
                        'idform'    => 'p-runcronjobs',
                    );
                    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);
                    $ch       = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, LOCALURL);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                }
            }
            break;
}
```

**How can I avoid session problems with the cron and the multiple requests that are made using curl?**

Comment: Problem related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828975/php-garbage-collection-clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related to the use of:

```
session_set_cookie_params(time() + 3600);
or
setcookie('name', 'id', time()+3600, "/");
```

[PHP Garbage Collection clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828975/php-garbage-collection-clarification)

need work around it to solve and use after read the data from `Session` and if you have access to `php.ini` you can set Expiration to 0 to prevent garbage collector kill session.